# Assertion failure when trying to write data to Keychain

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdata, keychain

I am trying to write some array data to my keychain using the code below

```
    // set up keychain so I can write to it... or read if needed (specially for testing)
    KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeyKeychain" accessGroup:nil];

//    write
    NSData *dataarr = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:parsedRemoteSitesMutableArray];
     [keychain setObject:dataarr forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrGeneric)];
//    read
    NSData *myArr = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrGeneric)];
    NSArray *arrayCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myArr];
//    log
    NSLog(@"%@", arrayCopy);
```

as you can see I am converting my NSArray to NSData then trying to store the NSData into kSecAttrGeneric however I am reciving this error below when I tri to setObject:forKey

```
Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone applications/appname/appname/KeychainItemWrapper.m:268
2013-07-22 13:54:39.952 key[2167:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
*** First throw call stack:etc...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I think you need to set the object as a `CFDataRef` instead of `NSData`.  Also, consider using a utility that is a bit newer (this code is 3 years old).  For example: https://github.com/ObjColumnist/MCSMKeychainItem

Comment: CFDataRef didnt work unfortunately... regarding using that API I kinda try to stay away from API's as I then become reliant on that being up to date for future releases etc.

Comment: ???  Yet you are using this *old* API from Apple.  If that is the case then why not just using the security framework directly?  Pick out the important bits from the Apple code.

Comment: when you say old, has this API been deprecated? I realize its not up to date with ARC etc but what else about it makes it a less sutible option than 3rd party source?... im probably going to use the API you have supplied because I Have had such problems with this code.. but I just try to avoid this type of thing in most cases.

Comment: Well it was never introduced to begin with, so it can't really be "deprecated".  It was really just an example of how to do things 3 years ago.  Things change.  I don't think many other people will be using this code, so they will be reluctant to help since it requires effort (especially since you didn't even mention where you got this code from).  Using code that hasn't been touched in years is just in general not a great idea, as far as I'm concerned.  The biggest reason being that it's not working for you, so I recommend that you find another solution.

Comment: If using a third party solution is disagreeable for you, then you should do as I said above and try to pick out the important bits from that Apple sample and use them directly.  Many more people are using the Security framework directly and I'm sure you will get a better response.

Comment: okay thanks borrrden, I will look into that side of things further... as well as the 3rd party API.